# How to properly use an image slideshow in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem using jQuery Mobile 1.4.1 and jQuery 2.0 with a slideshow. I'm using JQM and Phonegap build to make an android application. Once you log into the application, in the main screen there's a slideshow which rotates a couple images. The problem is I don't know what's the proper way to initialize the slideshow in jQM.

I'm new with JQM and I'm a bit lost on the event triggering order, I've initialized the slideshow code in the pagecreate event, however it causes the slideshow to initialize every time I navigate to the main page.

What I'm expecting is to find an equivalent to jQuery $(document).ready() to execute it just once and keep the images loaded in cache to avoid the data loss and the faster response from the slider. Can anyone tell me where should I initialize the slideshow to be ready as soon as page loads just as $(document).ready()?

**UPDATE 02/25/2014**

I'm using Camera Slideshow (http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) and the slider works properly, but it initializes every time I load or navigate to the main page, which makes it so slow and sometimes gives the impression that it's not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This isn't a question, this is a request!

Comment: The initial description was too long and hard to understand, made it shorter and more clear